# Writing data through VIEW using TDCH

Tags: view, teradata

I was trying use TDCH connector to load the data from Hive table to Teradata table. But, I want to load the data into the targt table (in teradata) via VIEW instead of accessing the table directly.

**So, is there a way to load the data to target table through the VIEW?**
There is an option called "tdch.output.teradata.data.dictionary.use.xview" but setting this option to true didn't help me either.

**Below is a sample TDCH job I was using**:

hadoop jar $TDCH_JAR

com.teradata.connector.common.tool.ConnectorExportTool

-Dmapred.job.queue.name=

-libjars $HIVE_LIB_JARS

-classname com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver

-url jdbc:teradata:///

-username xxxxx

-password xxxxx

-jobtype hive 

-fileformat textfile 

-nummappers 10 

-method internal.fastload 

-separator "\u0009" 

-sourcedatabase  

-sourcetable  

-sourcefieldnames "" 

-targettable  

-targetfieldnames "" 

-stagedatabase  

-forcestage true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try using '-method batch.insert'? Based on [this](https://forums.teradata.com/forum/tools/loading-into-views-using-tpt-0) developer exchange post, fastload sessions don't support loading views but regular sql sessions should work fine (TDCH's internal.fastload method uses fastload sessions, while batch.insert uses sql sessions).